# estoy creando una pagina web y para que cuando se click a cierto botón se guarde en base de dato

Tags: php, html

estoy creando una pagina web y necesito que cuando le de click al botón de comprar se registren los datos del producto en la base de datos en una tabla diferente, los datos que trato de enviar ya vienen de la base de datos ahora necesito insertarlos de vuelta para saber que productos se guardan cuando se les da click pero en la base pero solo me registra campos vacíos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Y?... Que quieres que hagamos? No sabemos la estructura de tu código, no agregaste tu código, como podremos ayudarte sin tu código? No somos adivino!!! Entonces, quiere que te hagamos la tarea? Primero haz [tour] y luego mira y lee bien [ask] y luego edita tu pregunta agregando tu código ...